# How to make a triangular plane with edges of arbitrary sizes?

Tags: edges

I want to make a triangular plane with arbitrary lengths.  I've seen lots of tutorials explaining how to make right triangles, isosceles triangles, etc., but I could not find anything for triangles with specific lengths that are not "special cases".

In FreeCAD I'd use constraints to do this, but the constraints system in Blender doesn't look like it supports doing things like setting distances between two vertices in a plane.

I could do a bunch of math to calculate the X, Y, Z positions of each vertex in 3D space and set the coordinates directly, but that is super tedious.  Is there an easier way?

So as an example, how would I create a triangular plane in Blender with edge lengths of 80mm, 95mm, and 110mm?  TIA

[image: A triangular plane with edge lengths of 80mm, 95mm, and 110mm]

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the edge length display and set the Pivot Point to Active you can deform a triangle to fit those dimensions. First set one side, then the other from one of the 2 first vertices and then rotate the second edge until the third fits in length. I think if you have the coordinates it'd be more precise to just copy them tbh
[image]

Another way would be to use a triangle angle calculator like this one:
https://www.calculator.net/triangle-calculator.html?vc=&vx=95&vy=80&va=&vz=110&vb=&angleunits=d&x=80&y=25

[image]

You can start with a single vertex and then extrude it 110 to make c, and extrude the same vertex 95 to make b, then just rotate it 45.207.

Comment: Interesting, will have to try these, thanks.  I'm still hoping for an easier method though!  Maybe this should be a Blender extension...

Comment: Yea, it's odd how blender is missing such basic tools for mildly precise modeling. I guess it wasn't meant to be CAD to begin with but it's still pretty frustrating how round about it is to make something basic like a non-equilateral triangle... I'm sure this in particular is super easy to do with python or geometry nodes but it should come stock